# Retrieving/Accessing Data from Curl JSON Request in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm having issues figuring out how to access the response from the following API request. Whilst the public API is simple and returns JSON that I can throw into object/array, I'm not quite understanding how to access the response of the request with API keys .etc. Ultimately I would like to be able to access items in a similar way to the public API:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($contents, true); 
//PRINT IT
echo $json['something']['something'];
```

This is the code supplied in the development API docs:

```
$apikey = "xxx";
$apisecret = "yyy";

$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey='.$apiKey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

If I try and dump $obj, it returns '1'.

```
//DEBUGGING
echo '<pre>';print_r($obj);exit;
```

This is what the response should look like:

```
{
"success" : true,
"message" : "",
"result" : [{
        "Currency" : "DOGE",
        "Balance" : 0.00000000,
        "Available" : 0.00000000,
        "Pending" : 0.00000000,
        "CryptoAddress" : "DLxcEt3AatMyr2NTatzjsfHNoB9NT62HiF",
        "Requested" : false,
        "Uuid" : null

    }, {
        "Currency" : "BTC",
        "Balance" : 14.21549076,
        "Available" : 14.21549076,
        "Pending" : 0.00000000,
        "CryptoAddress" : "1Mrcdr6715hjda34pdXuLqXcju6qgwHA31",
        "Requested" : false,
        "Uuid" : null
    }
]
```

}

Here's the API documentation: https://bittrex.com/Home/Api

Also, the above code automatically prints the response on the page, what line is printing it all?

I'm quite new to API's so sorry if this is a daft question, I just can't get my head round it.

Thanks

/////RESOLVED

I added the following lines of code and it worked.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Why dont you simply follow the documentation

Comment: @IndraKumarS As mentioned, I'm new to API's and simply asked why I couldn't access the response as an object/array. I've read the documentation but to no avail (that I can interpret anyway). I'm getting a response from the server, I just don't know how to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out....

```
<?php
$contents ='{
"success" : true,
"message" : "Test Message",
"result" : [{
        "Currency" : "DOGE",
        "Balance" : 0.00000000,
        "Available" : 0.00000000,
        "Pending" : 0.00000000,
        "CryptoAddress" : "DLxcEt3AatMyr2NTatzjsfHNoB9NT62HiF",
        "Requested" : false,
        "Uuid" : null

    }, {
        "Currency" : "BTC",
        "Balance" : 14.21549076,
        "Available" : 14.21549076,
        "Pending" : 0.00000000,
        "CryptoAddress" : "1Mrcdr6715hjda34pdXuLqXcju6qgwHA31",
        "Requested" : false,
        "Uuid" : null
    }
]
}';

$json = json_decode($contents, true); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json); 
echo "</pre><br>";

echo "Success is ".$json['success']."<br>";  // Here success is a boolean
echo "Message is ".$json['message']."<br>"; // Here message is a string
echo "In Result  first currency is ".$json['result'][0]['Currency']."<br>"; //Here result is an array...So Indexs should be mentioned... then string name
echo "In Result  second currency is  ".$json['result'][1]['Currency']."<br>"; 
      ?>
```

Output will be like this

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => Test Message
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Currency] => DOGE
                    [Balance] => 0
                    [Available] => 0
                    [Pending] => 0
                    [CryptoAddress] => DLxcEt3AatMyr2NTatzjsfHNoB9NT62HiF
                    [Requested] => 
                    [Uuid] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Currency] => BTC
                    [Balance] => 14.21549076
                    [Available] => 14.21549076
                    [Pending] => 0
                    [CryptoAddress] => 1Mrcdr6715hjda34pdXuLqXcju6qgwHA31
                    [Requested] => 
                    [Uuid] => 
                )

        )

)

Success is 1
Message is Test Message
In Result first currency is DOGE
In Result second currency is BTC
```